# Remove empty blocks from the Richtextbox without losing formatting

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I want to remove empty/unwanted spaces and carriage return from my `RichTextBox` or `TextRange`. Below is the code what I tried. However although I am able to remove the empty spaces but at the same time the formatting is lost too.

I understand that the moment I set `textRange.Text` the formatting is lost.

I do not know how to move ahead with this.

```
string findword = findWord.Text;
string replaceword = replaceText.Text;

        TextRange textRange = LoadXamlPackage(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);

        string[] lines = textRange.Text.Trim().Split('\r');

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (lines[i].Contains(findword) && replaceword == string.Empty)
            {
                lines[i] = "";
            }
        }

        textRange.Text = string.Join(" ", lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

string findword = findWord.Text;
string replaceword = replaceText.Text;

```
    TextRange textRange = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);

    string[] lines = textRange.Text.Trim().Split('\r');

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (lines[i].Contains(findword) && replaceword == string.Empty)
            {
                lines[i] = "";
            }
        }
        //textRange.Text = string.Join("", lines);         

        string rtf = string.Empty;
        MemoryStream objmemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        textRange.Save(objmemoryStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
        rtf = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(objmemoryStream.ToArray());           
        rtf = rtf.Replace(findword, replaceword);  
        MemoryStream objmemoryStream1 = new MemoryStream(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(rtf));
        rtfTestResult.SelectAll();
        rtfTestResult.Selection.Load(objmemoryStream1, DataFormats.Rtf);
```

When I uncomment the below line the formatting is completely lost -- 
 textRange.Text = string.Join("", lines);